# changing a group of textbox controls to ReadOnly = false

Tags: c#

I have a group of textbox controls which I want to change out of ReadOnly. My code snippet is below. The ReadOnly line gives error "control does not have a definition of ReadOnly..." I believe the issue has to do with the ReadOnly functionality being in the TextBoxBase class. How can I get around this and have access to the TextBoxBase class?

```
        foreach (Control c in fraPParameters.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Label)
            {
                c.Visible = false;
                c.Text = string.Empty;
                c.Tag = string.Empty;
                tt.SetToolTip(c, null);
            }

            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                c.Visible = false;
                c.ReadOnly = false;
                c.Text = string.Empty;
                c.Tag = string.Empty;
                tt.SetToolTip(c, null);
                c.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you give a try with c.Properties.ReadOnly = false

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Type Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is) which tests whether an expression can be converted to a specified type and, if it can be, casts it to a variable of that type.

> When using the type pattern to perform pattern matching, is tests
>   whether an expression can be converted to a specified type and, if it
>   can be, casts it to a variable of that type. It is a straightforward
>   extension of the is statement that enables concise type evaluation and
>   conversion. The general form of the is type pattern is:
>
> ```
> expr is type varname
> ```

**Example**

```
if (sender is TextBox textBox) 
{
    textBox.Visible = false;
    textBox.ReadOnly = false;
    textBox.Text = string.Empty;
    textBox.Tag = string.Empty;
    ...
```

Also you might want to just use a switch statement with pattern matching as mentioned by [Callum Watkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4415734/callum-watkins) in the comments

```
foreach (Control c in fraPParameters.Controls)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case TextBox textbox:
            textbox.Visible = false;
            textbox.ReadOnly = false;
            textbox.Text = string.Empty;
            textbox.Tag = string.Empty;
            //...
            break;
        case Label label:
            label.Visible = false;
            label.Text = string.Empty;
            label.Tag = string.Empty;
            //...
            break;

    }
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[is (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#var)

> Checks if an object is compatible with a given type, or (starting with
>   C# 7.0) tests an expression against a pattern.

[Using pattern matching switch statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements)

Comment: A `switch` expression using a type pattern might be well suited to OPs code as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#type-pattern

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `c` variable is still typed as `Control`, even though we just checked whether the object reference it points to is really a `TextBox`. The conditional check doesn't change the underlying type of the reference variable, and the base `Control` type doesn't support the `ReadOnly` property.

There are several ways to get around this. We already have an answer using the new `is` casting for C# 7. But try this if you can't use that yet (which is still a lot of people):

```
foreach (Control c in fraPParameters.Controls)
{
    var lbl = c as Label;
    var box = c as TextBox;

    if (lbl != null)
    {
        lbl.Visible = false;
        lbl.Text = string.Empty;
        lbl.Tag = string.Empty;
        tt.SetToolTip(c, null);
    }

    if (box != null)
    {
        box.Visible = false;
        box.ReadOnly = false;
        box.Text = string.Empty;
        box.Tag = string.Empty;
        tt.SetToolTip(c, null);
        box.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: Up-vote, as you actually explained the problem...i was all like, here read this, and this, and do this, sorted...